# Simple update Controller works in dev/test but fails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a page where users can update limited parts of their profile with just an authentication token from an email (think updating Twitter notifications without logging in).

It works on development and in test, but on production it fails to update the values (but doesn't raise an exception).

There are 2 controller methods, the method for Show will opt the person out of emails. The Update method is a checkbox toggle that will let them opt in or out. The first one, the Show method, works fine on production. The second method, the Update one, doesn't.

```
def show
  if attribute = params[:opt_out_attr]
    user.update!("#{attribute}": false)
  end
end

def update
  user.update!(update_params)

  redirect_to users_limited_edit_path
end
```

The only other difference I could find is in checking the network logs is that on development, submitting the form responds with a 302 and on production, it responds with a 301.

Any ideas why this would fail in production only, even though Show works?

Comment: plz update a request log in production.log (maybe Rails.root/log/production.log)

Comment: Please add the `update_params` and the request logs.

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic.

As a rule of thumb, do not build model attributes with what's in params. One can add who knows what in those params and messes up your app.

```
# NO
if attribute = params[:opt_out_attr]
  user.update!("#{attribute}": false)
end

# YES - something like this
if attribute = permitted_attribute?(params[:opt_out_attr])
  user.update_attribute(attribute, false)
end

def permitted_attribute?(param)
  User.new.attributes.keys.include?(param)
end
```